# modifying android_tutorial_pubsub. able to connect master on pc but roswtf and rxgraph suggests error

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS community,

I'm trying to modify the [android_tutorial_pubsub](https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse?repo=android#hg%2Fandroid_tutorial_pubsub) in hope that the roscore is started on my PC instead of on Android.
I started roscore and set ROS_IP as well as ROS_MASTER_URI.

All I did to the code was delete

```
rosCore = RosCore.newPrivate();
rosCore.start();
try {
  rosCore.awaitStart();
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
talker = new Talker();

nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(rosCore.getUri());
```

and add:

```
nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(URI.create("http://192.168.13.7:11311"));
```

so the code looks like this

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package org.ros.android.tutorial.pubsub;

import java.net.URI;

import android.os.Bundle;
//import org.ros.RosCore;
import org.ros.android.MessageCallable;
import org.ros.android.RosActivity;
import org.ros.android.views.RosTextView;
import org.ros.node.NodeConfiguration;
import org.ros.node.NodeMainExecutor;
import org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.R;
import org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Talker;

    /**
     * @author damonkohler@google.com (Damon Kohler)
     */
    public class MainActivity extends RosActivity {
    
    //  private RosCore rosCore;
      private RosTextView<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> rosTextView;
      private Talker tal
```

ker;

```
  public MainActivity() {
    super("Pubsub Tutorial", "Pubsub Tutorial");
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    rosTextView = (RosTextView<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String>) findViewById(R.id.text);
    rosTextView.setTopicName("/chatter");
    rosTextView.setMessageType("std_msgs/String");
    rosTextView
        .setMessageToStringCallable(new MessageCallable<String, org.ros.message.std_msgs.String>() {
          @Override
          public String call(org.ros.message.std_msgs.String message) {
            return message.data;
          }
        });
  }

  @Override
  protected void init(NodeMainExecutor nodeMainExecutor) {
//    rosCore = RosCore.newPrivate();
//    rosCore.start();
//    try {
//      rosCore.awaitStart();
//    } catch (Exception e) {
//      throw new RuntimeException(e);
//    }
    talker = new Talker();
    NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPrivate();
//    nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(URI.create("http://192.168.13.7:11311"));
    nodeMainExecutor.execute(talker, nodeConfiguration);
    nodeMainExecutor.execute(rosTextView, nodeConfiguration);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // RosCore should be shut down last since running Nodes will attempt to
    // unregister at shutdown.
//    rosCore.shutdown();
  }
}
```

when running, android is able to show Hello World n. so I assume android is then the two nodes talker and ros_text_view is able to connect the my master on PC.
but as I called roswtf, i got the following error:

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
Package: beginner_tutorials
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
connection to [/android_gingerbread/ros_text_view] timed out
connection to [/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker] timed out
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 2 error(s).

ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /android_gingerbread/ros_text_view
 * /rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker->/android_gingerbread/ros_text_view (/chatter)
```

Now I wonder whether the connection really succeeded, and what could possibly cause this conflict.
btw why can't I use rostopic pub to publish here?I tried `rostopic pub /chatter std_msg/String abc` but abc didn't show on my AVD. Did I miss anything?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30692/modifying-android_tutorial_pubsub.-able-to-connect-master-on-pc-but-roswtf-and-rxgraph-suggests-error/) by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2073/amigo/) on 2012-04-06**:
Did you mean to comment out the line //    nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(URI.create("http://192.168.13.7:11311"));?

**Comment by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on 2012-04-11**:
sorry the code was wrong. In my own code this line wasn't commented out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

turned out this is a issue with AVD. If I use AVD, and need to forward port, which is very inconvenient.

also `NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPrivate();` set Master default to itself. change it to `NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPublic()` and then `nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(URI.create("http://192.168.13.7:11311"));`

---

Originally posted by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) with karma: 61 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1